# How to copy maps from adventure books

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, map-making, battle-map

I recently bought a DnD 5e starter set and with it came the adventure book of the Lost Mine of Phandelver. It had a few maps with it. Now the problem is, I'm not sure how I should get those maps on a separate physical grid.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a scanner, scale it up, and print it. Or you can buy very nice digital copies from the artist Mike Schley, and print them.

Go to staples or office Depot and ask about engineering prints. You should be able to get a large map printed for a few dollars.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a scanner, most mobile phones have cameras that are good enough. You can read normal-sized text on a full-size legal document in the images from my 7-year-old iPhone. So it shouldn't be hard to take several closer images of the original map, use pretty much any photo-editing software to get it reasonably lined up, then print it normally.

There will likely be some distortion between the images unless you're good with editing software, but I think it would still look better than trying to hand-draw it, and much less work. And if the maps are small enough, you might get away with just taking one picture of the entire thing.

If you want to minimize noticeable distortions, take more images than you need. If 4 pictures in a square pattern is sufficient, take 9 or 16 and just use the middles. Most of the distortion will be towards the edges of the photo, so the closer your crop is to the middle, the better it will look. Also, take the pictures with the camera pointed straight down at the page and centered on the area you're capturing. Don't take a picture of the top of the page from the bottom of the page, or you'll get a bad perspective effect that's difficult to adjust in the software.

Also, you can scale the image up by reducing the DPI so it covers multiple physical sheets of paper. Then print it out, and literally cut and paste the results into one big gaming mat (scotch tape works pretty well too). Pasting it onto cardboard or poster board is probably best, so any miniatures you're using stay upright better, but if you're playing on a tabletop or counter, you can get away with plain paper.